# Shiny `showNotification` no longer working with `dashboardthemes`

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Once `dashboardthemes` is loaded it seems that bootstrap notification style no longer works (they are all displayed as gray i.e. default one).

Below 2 Shiny application, the first which appears to work fine, the second which shows the problem.

Does someone knows how to manage/fix this?

Note: `dashboardthemes` seems to have the same impact regarding buttons, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266594/cant-custom-the-size-argument-of-shinybsbsbutton)

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboardPlus)
require(dashboardthemes)

# APP #1: WORKING
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("show_default", "Show Default"),
    actionButton("show_message", "Show Message"),
    actionButton("show_warning", "Show Warning"),
    actionButton("show_error", "Show Error")
  ),
  
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$show_default, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_message, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "message")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_warning, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "warning")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_error, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "error")
    })
  }
)


# APP #2: WITH STYLING ISSUE
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    title = "hello",
    
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(title = "hello"),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    
    body = dashboardBody(
      shinyDashboardThemes(
        theme = "grey_light"
      ),
      
      fluidPage(
        actionButton("show_default", "Show Default"),
        actionButton("show_message", "Show Message"),
        actionButton("show_warning", "Show Warning"),
        actionButton("show_error", "Show Error")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$show_default, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_message, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "message")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_warning, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "warning")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$show_error, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.", type = "error")
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the dashboardthemes package set a single background colour for all notifications even if they had a different status.
I've fixed this in the latest v1.1.2 release of the package which is now available on GitHub. It will take several days to release on CRAN.

Comment: Great, thanks for your work! Maybe you can link to the GitHub issue

Comment: This was the pull request: https://github.com/nik01010/dashboardthemes/pull/30

Comment: Great job, thanks, it indeed works fine! Any chance you fix the issue with shinyBS::bsButton? When style is set to "default" the extra arguments such as "size" does not work. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266594/cant-custom-the-size-argument-of-shinybsbsbutton